# How to monitor the size of the data sent by HttpURLConnection?

Tags: java, post, httpurlconnection

I tried to display the size of the data already sent by the `OutputStreamWriter` but seems the `write` method is kind of like asynchronized which means if the file is 60M and the upload rate is 200K/s, the output only displays one line of "Data sent: 61210K" (or whatever large number ) instead of what's supposed to be (a small number per second)

Did I miss something?

code piece:

```
Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(out, POST_ENCODING);
char[] buf = new char[1024];
int read = 0;
long bytes = 0;
while ((read = reader.read(buf)) >= 0) {
    bytes += read;
    if (System.currentTimeMillis() - lastMsgTimeStamp > 1000) {
        lastMsgTimeStamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Data sent: " + (bytes / 1024) + " K");
    }
    writer.write(buf, 0, read);
}
writer.flush();
```

Comment: What is `out` which `OutputStreamWriter` wraps ? An underlying `StreamEncoder` would write to that.

Comment: It's just OutputStream returned by java.net.URLConnection.getOutputStream()

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `reader` is `InputStreamReader`, you are tracking how many characters being read/sent, not the number of bytes. If you are not actually working with the text in between reading/writing then you could use the standard `InputStream`/`OutputStream` to monitor the byte count.

Also, `lastMsgTimeStamp` has no declaration, is it being set to `System.currentTimeMillis()` somewhere outside your example?

In either case, `OutputSteamWriter`, along with the rest of the `java.io.*` package, is blocking. So when `write` is called your thread stops until it completes. However there is some buffering going on, by the `StreamEncoder` in `OutputStreamWriter` and also by the implementation of `OutputStream` returned by `URLConnection`. Neither buffer such large amounts of data, so your problem is likely somewhere else.